# SQL STORED PROCEDURE SAVING INTO VARIABLE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can anybody spot the problem with this stored procedure?  mysql is reporting the following error:
1048 Column 'categoryID' cannot be null

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE catalogue_assign_product_to_subcategory(
    IN inProductId INT, 
    IN insubCategoryId INT)

     BEGIN

     DECLARE catID INT;

     SELECT subcategoryParent FROM tblSubcategory 
         WHERE subcategoryID =  insubCategoryId INTO catID;

    INSERT INTO tblProdCat (productID, categoryID)
       VALUES (inProductId, 'catID');


  END
```

Answer (score 0):

'catID' should be without the singlequotes in the INSERT statement.
I guess the field is defined as INT, you now try to insert a STRING

```
   INSERT INTO tblProdCat (productID, categoryID)
   VALUES (inProductId, catID);
```